# I have some doubts about the implementation about run() of FutureTask

Tags: java

In java.util.concurrent.FutureTask, the run() has been implemented as below:

```
public void run() {
    ...
            V result;
            boolean ran;
            try {
                result = c.call();
                ran = true;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                result = null;
                ran = false;
                setException(ex);
            }
            if (ran)
                set(result);
    ...
}
```

Why not be implemented like:

```
public void run() {
    ...
            V result;
            try {
                result = c.call();
                set(result);
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                result = null;
                setException(ex);
            }     
    ...
}
```

Is there any particular consideration on this?

Comment: Because they don't want an exception that occurred in the set method to be stored as "the" exception of the task?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt THX~ I think you are right.